# Update table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like where my Event column is blank.

[image]

The logic is simple. The customer's SaleDate can appear one time or more than one time. We first check **year** for each customer and if **year** is same then we check the **SaleDate** and thus set the event.

Can anyone please help how I can update! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

```
UPDATE table1 t SET Event =
    (WITH v AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY Year, SaleDate)
       AS row_num, id
    FROM table1)
    SELECT row_num FROM v
    WHERE id = t.id);
```

Comment: Being a correlated subquery, I think that that subquery will only ever return one row in each invocation and so it can only generate `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query. Replace the TableName by your actual table name

```
UPDATE TableName SET [Event] = SeqTable.Seq
FROM  
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY [Year],SaleDate) AS Seq
     FROM TableName) 
     AS SeqTable
WHERE TableName.id = SeqTable.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Event, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Year ORDER BY SaleDate) rn
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE CTE SET Event = rn
```